# Backtracing Sudoku solver

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, sudoku

I have made a backtracking Sudoku solver in Python but it's working quite slow.

Originally, It had been working on 4 by 4 grids, which worked fine.

But now, trying to solve 9 by 9 grids takes a very long time.

I haven't found out the exact reason but I feel that there is one major flaw that is making it so time consuming, However, I could not identify it.

I have seen similar programs and they seem faster.

The main class is `Sudoku`, however specifically the code which solves the Sudoku is in `Sudoku.solve()`.

The Sudoku array is a NumPy array.

```
import numpy
def is_proper_sudoku(iterable):
    count = {}
    for val in iterable:
        if val in count.keys():
            count[val] += 1
        else:
            count[val] = 1
    for var in count.keys():
        if var != 0 and count[var] > 1:
            return False
    return True

# CLASSES
class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size #Size for future use

        map_list = [[0 for val in range(size**2)] for val in range(size**2)]
        self.map = numpy.array(map_list, numpy.int8) #Sudoku Body

        self.empty = [(each_y, each_x) for each_y in range(size**2) for each_x in range(size**2)]

        self.strides = self.map.itemsize * numpy.array([size**4, size, size**2, 1])

        self.bulge_blocks = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(self.map, (size, size, size, size), self.strides)
        self.blocks = numpy.array([row.flatten() for row in self.bulge_blocks]).reshape(size, size, size**2) #Defining Blocks

    def solve(self): #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

        if not self.check_valid:
            return False

        y, x = 0, 0 #Setting the starting position.

        done = False

        global tried, changes

        tried = [] #Stores the not working:(<y location>, <x location>, <inserted_value>, <arrray_string>) #inserted_value or then_array
        changes = [] #All Changes: Tuples: (<last y location>, <last x location>, <last value>)

        while not done: #Looping

            if self.map[y, x] == 0: #Making sure that the space is empty

                self.update_blocks()

                for num in range(1, self.size**2+1): #All the possible numbers
                    #print()
                    #print('Not in tried?', not (y, x, num, self.map.dumps()) in tried)
                    print((y, x, num))

                    if num not in self.map[y] and num not in self.map.T[x] and\
                            num not in self.blocks[y//self.size, x//self.size]\
                            and not (y, x, num, self.map.dumps()) in tried: #Checking if no numbers that make it invalid

                        #print('Making the right way', self.map[y, x], 'at', y, x, 'Val: ', num)

                        tried.append((y, x, num, self.map.dumps())) #For future reference       
                        changes.append((y, x)) #You need to maintain a record


                        self.map[y, x] = num #Changing

                        break

                    else:
                        #print(num, 'Not Valid at', y, x)

                        map_string = self.map.dumps()

                        # HERE'S THE CHANGE
                        if (y, x, num, map_string) in tried and num == self.size**2:
                            try:
                                last_y, last_x = changes.pop()
                                self.map[last_y, last_x] = 0
                                y, x = last_y, last_x
                                #print('Making the wrong way', self.map[y, x], 'at', last_y, last_x, 'Val: ', 0)
                            except IndexError:
                                return False

                            self.update_blocks()

                        else:
                            tried.append((y, x, num, self.map.dumps())) #For future reference
                            continue

            else:
                if y == (self.size**2)-1 and x == (self.size**2)-1:
                    self.solved = self.map
                    break                

                elif x < (self.size**2)-1:
                    x = x + 1

                elif x == (self.size**2)-1:
                    y = y + 1
                    x = 0

                print('Going over to change the location to', y, x)


    def check_valid(self):
        for major_array in [self.map, self.map.T]:
            for sub_array in major_array:
                if not is_proper_sudoku(sub_array):
                    return False
        return True

    def update_blocks(self):
        self.bulge_blocks = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(self.map, (self.size, self.size, self.size, self.size), self.strides)
        self.blocks = numpy.array([row.flatten() for row in self.bulge_blocks]).reshape(self.size, self.size, self.size**2) #Redefining Blocks 


    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.map))

main = Sudoku(3)
##print(main)
##print()
##main.solve()
##print()
##print(main)
```

**I think I have the error in the program. I think that I should start with the cell which has the least possibilities. This might reduce the running time of the program. Can you implement that idea in the program? I have no idea how to do so?**

Comment: Not an answer, but if you break up the `solve()` method into smaller, separate methods, you could profile the code for the 4*4 case and see where time is being lost.

Comment: What is the purpose of the lines:
            `tried = tried`
            `changes = changes`
at the beginning of the loop? (I.e. why assign again those variables to themselves?)

Comment: @Attilio I was using them while debugging as global variables. Thanks I'll change it.

Comment: Breaking up the `solve()` method will also make your code more readable.

Comment: @wei2912 Do you have any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: @DhruvSomani - Sometimes your code works for me, sometimes it doesn't. This is a very bad sign. It's hard to have an uninitialized (random) memory in python, but you've found a way to do so.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: @200_success The new code works fine but my question is not completely answered. The second code showed improvement but it is not efficient enough to solve 9 by 9 Sudokus. I still need an answer for my question.

Comment: Did you read the link in my comment about what to do in that case? You can either wait for more answers or post a fresh follow-up question. (If you had more points, you could also offer a bounty.)

Answer (score 5):

**Function calling bug**

```
if not self.check_valid:
        return False
```

You omitted the parenthesis, this means you are talking about the value of the function object, that is always true. So this check is basically jumped.

The fix is:

```
if not self.check_valid():
        return False
```

**Usage of built-ins : `Counter` and `all`**

The definition of `is_proper_sudoku` that you use feels low-level as you re-invent the `Counter` and `all` built-ins:

```
def is_proper_sudoku(iterable):
    count = {}
    for val in iterable:
        if val in count.keys():
            count[val] += 1
        else:
            count[val] = 1
    for var in count.keys():
        if var != 0 and count[var] > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

You could write that as:

```
def is_proper_sudoku(iterable):
    count = collections.Counter(iterable)
    return all(not (var != 0 and count[var] > 1) for var in count.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you find a way to reduce the time consumption.

Comment: You see the function `is_proper_sudoku` is executed only once. The time consumption wouldn't be affected much by that.

Comment: @DhruvSomani Yes, but that does not mean it should not be improved :)

Comment: Okay! Will make the changes.

Comment: @DhruvSomani wait, never edit the code in the question. After making the improvements, wait a couple of days and ask a follow-up

Comment: For the case of a 9 by 9 grid. The `tried` is getting exceptionally large. To reduce the memory I had pickled the arrays and then inserted them in it. Any way to reduce the memory used in `tried`?

Comment: @DhruvSomani Why do you need `tried` at all? The backtracking search should avoid trying the same thing more than once by design.

Comment: @JanneKarila What do you exactly mean? If there is no `tried` then the process would repeat over and over again. 'The backtracking search should avoid trying the same thing more than once by design.' How should I design the backtracking search so that it does not try a single thing more than once.

Comment: @DhruvSomani I see you reset `self.map[last_y, last_x] = 0` when backtracking and lose information on which value you tried last. You should keep that information so that the next iteration tries the next value instead of starting from 1.

Comment: @JanneKarila Oh! So you mean that instead of replacing it by 0, I should simply increase it by 1 (If it's still valid and is not 10) ?

Comment: @DhruvSomani Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @JanneKarila I used your idea and implemented it in the program. I have observed that the time consumption has decreased by about 50%. But still it is not efficient to solve 9 by 9 Sudokus. I have pasted my code in an update in the question.

Comment: @Caridorc I think I have found a way to reduce the run time of the program. Do you think it would work? I have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements in the program but it is still not efficient enough to solve the program.

```
import numpy

# CLASSES
class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

        self.map = numpy.zeros((self.size**2, self.size**2)).astype(numpy.int8) #Sudoku Body

        self.strides = self.map.itemsize * numpy.array([size**4, size, size**2, 1])

        self.loops = 0
        self.backs = 0

    def solve(self): #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms     
        y, x = 0, 0 #Setting the starting position.
        num = 1



        changes = [] #All Changes: Tuples: (<last y location>, <last x location>, <inserted value>)

        while True: #Looping
            print(self)

            self.loops += 1

            self.update_blocks()

            if num not in self.map[y] and num not in self.map.T[x] and\
                    num not in self.blocks[y//self.size, x//self.size]: #Checking if no numbers that make it invalid

                changes.append((y, x, num)) #Appending the movements to changes

                self.map[y, x] = num #Changing

                if y == (self.size**2)-1 and x == (self.size**2)-1:
                    break                

                elif x < (self.size**2)-1:
                    x = x + 1

                elif x == (self.size**2)-1:
                    y = y + 1
                    x = 0

                num = 1
                continue

            else:
                if num == self.size**2:
                    self.map[y, x] = 0

                    last_y, last_x, last_value = changes.pop()

                    while last_value == self.size**2:
                        self.map[last_y, last_x] = last_value
                        last_y, last_x, last_value = changes.pop()

                    self.map[last_y, last_x] = 0

                    y, x = last_y, last_x

                    num = last_value + 1

                    self.backs += 1

                else:
                    num += 1
                    continue

    def unsolve(self):
        self.map = numpy.zeros((self.size**2, self.size**2)).astype(numpy.int8)


    def update_blocks(self):
        self.bulge_blocks = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(self.map, (self.size, self.size, self.size, self.size), self.strides)
        self.blocks = numpy.array([row.flatten() for row in self.bulge_blocks]).reshape(self.size, self.size, self.size**2) #Redefining Blocks 


    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.map))


main = Sudoku(2)

##print(main)
##print()
##main.solve()
##print()
##print(main)
```